# Switch from mysqli_* to MySQLI object-oriented

Tags: php, oop

I'm a beginner in PHP and started my project using mysqli procedural code. And I now prefer use OOP instead of `mysqli_*`, But I couldn't fine any comprehensive resource to compare my codes and convert them to OOP.

For example I wrote:

```
$u_username = mysqli_real_escape_string($con , $u_username);
```

And I tried to covert that to OOP:

I tried this:

```
$u_username = mysqli::real_escape_string($u_username);
```

and

```
$u_username = $con -> real_escape_string($u_username);
```

and I don't know what the differences between them are.

I need a resource to compare all commands in MySQLi procedural and OOP.

Thank you.

Comment: See the table of contents in http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli.php

Comment: Here is all : http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[php.net](http://php.net/) is actually a very good resource for this purpose. In every function (method) of mysqli it gives examples for both oop and procedural way.

For example, `mysqli_query` examples also include the db connection in the examples:

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

I suggest you check php.net for every function you use and you will see the oop examples.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really the right place to ask for links to tutorials and other resources.

However, while you're looking around for resources online, I can answer your specific question in the hope that it's helpful.

The answer is quite simple: using `mysqli::....` means "call this method on the MySQLi class itself", whereas `$con->.....` means "call this method on my current MySQL connection."

I was not aware that `real_escape_string()` could be called on the class, so you should use the latter.

Comment: **This isn't really the right place to ask for links to tutorials and other resources**. I'm So sorry but I was very confused and thought I can find the resource like a table to compare them. I'll try to optimize my questions :)

Comment: @HamedMehraei: It's OK; you're learning, and that's not easy to do. Stack Overflow can seem a bit unwelcoming to newbies at first! :)   If my answer helped you please consider marking it as correct so it helps others too.

Comment: Unfortunately your answer couldn't satisfy me but your comment about what the difference between _mysqli::..._ and _$variable->..._ was helpful that couldn't help me ;)